# Change jdbc.properties with context.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, jdbc

I make Spring webapp and I use jdbc.properties files from DB. 
In applicationContext.xml I have this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:cfg/properties/jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

Now, I want to change place from my properties  from my DB , now I have context.xml file in tomcat and also context.xml in META-INF in webapp . 
 in context.xml I have  :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context path="/webapp" docBase="../webapp/webapp.war" displayName="webapp">
<Environment name="jdbc.driverClassName" override="false"     type="java.lang.String" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>  
<Environment name="jdbc.dialect" override="false" type="java.lang.String"   value="..."/>  
<Environment name="jdbc.databaseurl" override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="..."/>  
<Environment name="jdbc.username" override="false" type="java.lang.String" value=""/>  
<Environment name="jdbc.password" override="false" type="java.lang.String" value=""/>  
</Context>
```

What I need to change in applicationContext to webapp looking properties from context.xml , or better  how I can put in jdbc.properties values from tomcat context.xml file?

Comment: why do you need properties in context.xml additionally ?

Comment: Because, if I change something about DB, I don't want to change WAR  file. I change only context.xml in tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And that's where [JNDI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html) comes in... In your Tomcat's conf directory, `context.xml` file add:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/your_app_ds"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="username"
          password="password"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          maxActive="100"
          maxIdle="10"
          validationQuery="select 1"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="300000"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="100000"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          url="db_url"/>
```

Then in your Spring file all you need to do is to define JNDI entry like this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
                 jndi-name="jdbc/your_app_ds"
                 expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

This way Spring will create `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation instance and you'll get a hold of it via `dataSource` id.

Just do not forget to specify schema location for `jee` prefix:

```
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
```

and:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd"
```

Comment: This is working , but I try and now use contex.xml from tomcat with '<Context>
...
<Environment username="XY" ... type="java.lang.String"/>  
</Context>' , and than in java class use this values for properties and to make dataSource bean.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a propery holder bean like

```
<!-- Load values for configuration placeholders, evaluated at startup only -->
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="location" value="file:${user.dir}/jdbc.properties" />
</bean>
```